# Why does AVG query not work after a month in Postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I have been using this query in Postgres for a month, and it has been working fine:

```
SELECT
    DATE_TRUNC('hour', created_at::timestamp) AS datetime,
    AVG(temperature_1) as temperature_1
FROM
    main_data
WHERE
    created_at BETWEEN '2022-01-22 01:00:00' AND '2022-01-22 3:00:00'
GROUP BY 
    DATE_TRUNC('hour', created_at)
```

now when I use the query I get this error:

```
ERROR:  column "main_data.created_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 2: DATE_TRUNC('hour', created_at::timestamp) as datetime,
                           ^
SQL state: 42803
Character: 27
```

I have not done any update.

[image: This the created_at field in my Postgres database]

This the created_at field in my Postgres database

Comment: `GROUP BY 1` will also work.

Answer (score 1):

When using `group by` keywords your column format (with the cast, etc) should same format in group by operation

```sql
SELECT
DATE_TRUNC('hour', created_at::timestamp) as datetime,
AVG(temperature_1) as temperature_1
FROM  main_data
where created_at BETWEEN '2022-01-22 01:00:00' AND '2022-01-22 3:00:00'
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('hour', created_at::timestamp)
```

Comment: It works, Thanks a lot.
but I still wonders why the old query has been working for a month?

Comment: @hamzeh Did the table change? It's odd that `created_at` needs to be cast, it should already be a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

This would happen if the type of created_at changed to something which is not `timestamp`. For example, `timestamptz`.

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6c7232600415a26dc4f317f85c3d225c)

The casting should not be necessary.

Comment: Thanks in advance for your answer.
Nothing changed in the table fields. But, the counts of records reached 100,000,000.
Is this the reason?

Comment: I edited my question to add the field type in my Postgres database

Comment: @Hamzeh Record count makes no difference. The only explanation I know of is the one in my answer: your `created_at` field was probably `timestamp` and was recently changed to `timestamptz`.